# Javascript Date value not passing to the Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

To my ASP.NET MVC web application, I'm trying to apply a `full calendar` with create and view events.

For that, I found this amazing tutorial on [here](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2017/07/curd-operation-on-fullcalendar-in-aspnet-mvc.html) and I followed same.

All parts are working as same as the tutorial.

But when I try to create an event, for the controller it won't pass the selected date `Start` and `End`Date to the controller. Other data comes to the controller but the dates are not passing.

I tried in the script checking by console log and I found that the date values are written on the console when I hit submit. But only the dates are not passing.

Can you help me to find the error here?

This is the View

```
<div id="myModalSave" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Save Event</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="col-md-12 form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" id="hdEventID" value="0" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Subject</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtSubject" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Start</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="dtp1">
                            <input type="text" id="txtStart" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkIsFullDay" checked="checked" />  Is Full Day event</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="divEndDate" style="display:none">
                        <label>End</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="dtp2">
                            <input type="text" id="txtEnd" class="form-control" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Description</label>
                        <textarea id="txtDescription" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Theme Color</label>
                        <select id="ddThemeColor" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Default</option>
                            <option value="red">Red</option>
                            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                            <option value="black">Black</option>
                            <option value="green">Green</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Script

```
  $('#btnSave').click(function () {
            //Validation/
            if ($('#txtSubject').val().trim() == "") {
                alert('Subject required');
                return;
            }
            if ($('#txtStart').val().trim() == "") {
                alert('Start date required');
                return;
            }
            if ($('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') == false && $('#txtEnd').val().trim() == "") {
                alert('End date required');
                return;
            }
            else {
                var startDate = moment($('#txtStart').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                var endDate = moment($('#txtEnd').val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A").toDate();
                if (startDate > endDate) {
                    alert('Invalid end date');
                    return;
                }
            }

            var data = {
                EventID: $('#hdEventID').val(),
                Subject: $('#txtSubject').val().trim(),
                Start: $('#txtStart').val().trim(),
                End: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked') ? null : $('#txtEnd').val().trim(),
                Description: $('#txtDescription').val(),
                ThemeColor: $('#ddThemeColor').val(),
                IsFullDay: $('#chkIsFullDay').is(':checked')
            }
            SaveEvent(data);
            // call function for submit data to the server
        })

        function SaveEvent(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/home/SaveEvent',
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        //Refresh the calender
                        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
                        $('#myModalSave').modal('hide');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            })
        }
```

This is the model

```
public partial class EventsMain
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime? End_Date { get; set; }
        public bool IsFullDay { get; set; }
        public string Theme_Color { get; set; }
        public int Create_By { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created_Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    }
```

Controller

```
  public JsonResult SaveEvent(EventsMain e)
        {
            var status = false;

                if (e.Id > 0)
                {
                    //Update the event
                    var v = db.EventsMain.Where(a => a.Id == e.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {
                        v.Subject = e.Subject;
                        v.Start = e.Start;
                        v.End = e.End;
                        v.Description = e.Description;
                        v.IsFullDay = e.IsFullDay;
                        v.ThemeColor = e.ThemeColor;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                 e.Create_By = int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);

                 db.EventsMain.Add(e);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                status = true;

             
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }
```

Comment: Please show your controller API. What is the object model that the API action expect to receive?

Comment: @YongShun Hi. I have updated the question by adding the controller

Comment: Hi, based on the API action code attached, `EventsMain` doesn't have `Start` and `End` properties, you will get a compilation error. Are both properties should be  `Start_Date` and `End_Date`?

Comment: @YongShun Fist I thought it also. I have changed the ``Start_Date`` to ``Start`` and ``End_Date`` to ``End`` but nothing has changed. Still, the issue comes.

Comment: As your `EventsMain` class use `Start_Date` & `End_Date`, your JS side the `data` object should use `Start_Date` and `End_Date` properties name as well.

Comment: @YongShun I have added the changes I have done as a solution. But still it won't pass the data. I have rechecked with the tutorial. I still have the same code , but in the tutorial it passes the data to controller. Mine is none.